# What motors to use to guide tape with high speed

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, motors

My field isn't dealing with motors and such at all, however, I now need to build something that controls two motors.

So I have two guiding reels with tape between them, similar to old tape recorders. Now the important thing I want to control is the speed that the tape moves and the tension. Another important factor is that I want to be able to switch direction relatively fast.

So I went on the journey of figuring out what type of motors I need and it's quite overwhelming, there are so many types and when I read stuff online it's always "it depends".

What I am looking at now is buy two brushless dc motors with sensors that can sense the position, an Arduino and two motor drivers like the L6234 (https://www.st.com/en/motor-drivers/l6234.html). Then use the Arduino to control both motors.

I cannot find online if it is possible to change the tension in this way. My idea would be to use one motor to give a virtual load on the other motor to increase tension.

Is this possible using brushless dc motors and would my general setup up? Or do I need something completely different?

Comment: a simple method of keeping tension is with a pulley loaded with a mass...

Comment: @SolarMike a pulley would unspool the tape without having any counter pressure

Comment: Consider an endless loop...

Comment: @SolarMike I can't do an endless loop. The tape needs to stay still.....

Comment: I've seen endless ropes kept in tension on paper making machines traveling in excess of 8m/s, so do a diagram showing exactly what you have and what you want...